# В чем ошибка в коде с if и else?

Tags: php, ооп, if

Выводит на экран в любом случае "Введите коректное число1"
Код на PHP :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>ПХП ООП</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="chil">
        <button type="submit" name="do_sum"><p>Решить</p></button>
    </form>

<?php 
    trait Prim {
        public $numse = 15;

        public function SumLinePrim($numse)
        {
            return $this->numse * $this->get();
        }
    } 

    abstract class HtmlError 
    {
        public static function Error()
        {
             if(! is_int());
        }
    }

    class Glava extends Exception
    {
        use Prim;

        public $resheno;

        function __construct($resheno)
        {
            $this->resheno = $resheno;
        }

        public function get()
        {
            return $this->resheno;
        }

        public function getOtvet()
        {
            if(is_string($this->get($this->resheno))) {
                return print "Введите коректное число";
            } else {
                return $this->get() + $this->SumLinePrim($this->numse);
            }
        }
    }

    $data = $_POST;
    $errors = array();

    if(isset($data['do_sum'])) {
        $doc7 = new Glava($data['chil']);
        print "{$doc7->getOtvet()}";
    }

?>
```

Comment: ради всего святого, отформатируйте этот код. глаза кровоточат, когда пытаешься его читать. Такое ощущение, что вас штрафуют за каждую лишнюю строчку или фигурную скобку. https://github.com/samdark/fig-standards-ru/blob/master/accepted/ru/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md

Comment: @Ипатьев Плюсую.  За то и люблю Python, что там всё строго с отступами, и читать чужой код приятнее.

Comment: Интересно, что делает `if(! is_int());` ?

Answer (score 2):

Значение переданное POST запросом из формы

```
$data['chil']
```

всегда будет строкой, что бы вы не ввели, соответственно

```
is_string($this->get())
```

всегда будет `true` и всегда будет срабатывать

```
if(is_string($this->get($this->resheno))) {
    return print "Введите коректное число";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю (нет возможности быстро проверить), что данные приходящие в `$data['chil']` всегда являются строкой (`'5'` - строка, `5` - число, и `$data['chil']` содержит `'5'`), поэтому условие `is_string($this->get($this->resheno))` всегда `True` (кстати, метод `get` у Вас не принимает аргументов, можно написать `is_string($this->get())` или `is_string($this->resheno)`).

Можно преобразовать строку в число, но перед этим **нужно** проверить, **можно ли** строку преобразовать в число или нет, простой пример:

```
$a = '654654.6465';  //  $a - строка с числом ('654654.6465')
echo('Type $a: ');
var_dump($a); 
//  is_numeric проверяет, можно ли строку преобразовать в число или нет. 
echo("Можно преобразовать в число?: " . (int)is_numeric($a) . "\n");  
$a = (float)$a;  //  Преобразовываем; $a - число (654654.6465)
echo('Type $a: ');
var_dump($a);
echo("\n\n");

$a = 'string';  //  $a - просто строка
echo('Type $a: ');
var_dump($a);
// Т.к. $a нелься преобразовать в числу, is_numeric возвращает false
echo("Можно преобразовать в число?: " . (int)is_numeric($a) . "\n"); 
$a = (float)$a;  // Теперь $a содержит 0, что тоже число, и это может привести 
                 // к ОШИБКАМ в программе, поэтому перед преобразованием ВСЕГДА 
                 // НУЖНО проверять строку ф-ией is_numeric
echo('Type $a: ');
var_dump($a);
```

Вывод:

```
Type $a: string(11) "654654.6465"
Можно преобразовать в число?: 1
Type $a: float(654654.6465)


Type $a: string(6) "string"
Можно преобразовать в число?: 0
Type $a: float(0)
```

Документация: https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.is-numeric.php